# Question about number of descendants of bee population

Tags: combinatorics, exponential-function

There was a question on BBC Radio 4 this morning as follows:

> Alien bees invade Earth. On the third and fourth days of its life, each bee gives birth to a live clone, then dies at the end of its fourth day. The invasion begins with one bee. How many bees are there at the end of the twentieth day?

I wrote a computer program to calculate the answer, which in this case I believe is 48 bees (85 ever lived, of which 37 are dead).

I'm wondering if it's possible to derive a general formula for the number of bees alive on day N?

Comment: Should be possible to write down a linear recursion.  I expect there are several ways to do it, but one simple thought would be to count each type of bee (one day old, two days old, etc.)  and built the recursion that way.

Comment: The total population after $n$ days is equivalent to $$\frac{x^2+1}{x^3(x-1)^3}x^n$$ where $x>1$ denotes the unique positive root of the polynomial $$x^4-x-1$$

Comment: @Did - how did you derive that formula?

Comment: Use graph theory. Every bee is a set of 4 vertices (each representing a day). Its first vertex connects to a predecessor, its 3rd and 4th vertices connect to a successor.

Comment: @Did that deserves to be an answer.

Comment: @RobertFrost Any concrete application of this representation, which would be useful to solve the question at hand?

Comment: I came up with the same answer as given in the original post. The BBC website gives a different answer though...
http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/47CdWb5RGP4SRdb8t2nwBL3/puzzle-for-today

Comment: @dave I think I later found an error in my calculations - I wasn't incrementing the age of newborn bees from 1 to 2 on their first night. When I corrected that, I ended up with 200 as the BBC did. I still haven't figured out a general formula. The BBC say it's "related to the Fibonacci sequence" but don't give any specifics.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left [\begin {matrix}
0&0&1&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
\end {matrix}\right]^n\left [\begin {matrix} 1\\0\\0\\0\end {matrix}\right]$$
The total number of bees on day $n$ is the sum of the vector components of the result. It may need to use $n-1$ in the exponent if you count the start of the invasion as day 1.

Alternately:
$$\begin {align}b_n &= b_{n-2}+b_{n-3}\\a_n &= b_n + b_{n-1}+b_{n-2} +b_{n-3}\end{align}$$
I don't see a way to use just $a$, sadly.